# Sending a mail over network to a folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sendmail

I am trying to send a mail, in this case a gridview to a specified folder on my machine as to be able to view the message. I am thus sending the mail but it is not ending up in the folder. How can I do this?

I added this to web.config:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings >
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="ArianG@lr.co.za">
    <network host="staging.itmaniax.co.za"/>
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\testdump\emaildump\"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

This is my code for sending the gridview. (I presume I do not need SmtpClient as I do not want to connect to a port, either 25 or 587) :

```
private void MailReport()
{
    //*****************************************************
    string to = "arianul@gmail.com";
    string From = "ArianG@lr.co.za";
    string subject = "Report";
    string Body = "Good morning, Please view attachment<br> Plz Check d Attachment <br><br>";

    Body += GridViewToHtml(GridView1);

    Body += "<br><br>Regards,<br>Arian Geryts(ITManiax)";
    bool send = sendMail(to, From, subject, Body);

    if (send == true)
    {
        string CloseWindow = "alert('Mail Sent Successfully!');";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CloseWindow", CloseWindow, true);
    }
    else
    {
        string CloseWindow = "alert('Problem in Sending mail...try later!');";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CloseWindow", CloseWindow, true);
     }
    //*****************************************************

}

public bool sendMail(string to, string from, string subject, string body)
{
    bool k = false;
    try
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);
        msg.Subject = subject;

        AlternateView view;
        SmtpClient client;
        StringBuilder msgText = new StringBuilder();
        view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgText.ToString(), null, "text/html");
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(view);
        msgText.Append(" <html><body><br></body></html> <br><br><br>  " + body);

        //*****
        /*client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25);
        client.Host = "staging.itmaniax.co.za";
        client.Port = 25;

        //****
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(msg);*/

        k = true;     
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your mail Setting in web.config to:

```
  <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\smtp" />
```

This should do the trick. Alternativly you could change the setting via tha IIS gui, after you deployed the solution.

Kind regards.

/edit: of course you need a smtp client. The program has to fire the email message out to the smtp server. The message just gets picked up by IIS and stuffed into a folder.